# Lost Boyz lyrics from "Guiltiness" remix (Bob Marley - Chant Down Bablyon remix album)

Tags: lyrics

Hello and thanks in advance for your answers. I like this song a lot, but it seems that the only available lyrics are for the original Bob Marley song. I would like you to help me get this lyrics for the rap verse on the remix from the "Chant Down Babylon" remix album.

Although I speak English, it is not my primary language and that´s why I cannot figure it out myself.
this is the link:
[Guiltiness -  Bob Marley ft Mr Cheeks and Lost Boyz](https://youtu.be/JEPWQclHPD0?t=2m5s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% on these lyrics, but I think they're reasonably accurate.  I have a couple of gaps marked with [???]. *Note: The use of "they" instead of "their" is not a mistake, it's a common substitution in black American speech.*

If you are a fan of the Lost Boyz, you might enjoy their biggest hit, [Renee](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rZ7DBSzpaSY).

---

2:05
What you say, what we do?

We got these politicians coming through
with they crooked missions
nobody's hearing
plus we living in the worst conditions

a generation hooked on welfare
nobody cares
we representing drugs and violence
a shot, it clears
a street out
we got some parties
bringing heat out
I'm trying to get my life on layback
I kick my feet out

no doubt, sacrifice,
I need to feed my kids and wife
there's many things that we neglect
like we forgot to respect life, yo!

3:02

Yo, hey yo,
I represent this for those of us caught up in the struggle
to single moms who got their kids and plus a job to juggle
for those that listen grab ya pen and get ya note on
and read these politicians [???] to get they vote on

the world is spinnin'
Praise the Lord, it's still spinnin'
[???]
that's what we learnt in the beginnin'

you keep blowing up when somebody needs you
but never bite the hand that feeds you

Comment: Pretty accurate!

Answer (score 1):

~~ Answer removed ~~ question was about the raps not the Bob Marley lyric, which is available in a lot of places, for example

Here :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSSyPqhrK1Q

BTW, "Guiltiness" is from Bob Marley and the Wailers "Exodus" album
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exodus_(Bob_Marley_%26_the_Wailers_album)#Track_listing

Comment: Thanks for your response, but that is not the version I am looking for. Check the link in the question. Is kind of the same song, but I want to know what they are saying outside the riffs.

Comment: ah ok, you want the lyrics of the raps by MC Cheeks/Lost Boyz, not of the Bob Marley song they are mixed with ? Harder question...

Comment: Yes, that´s exactly what I am looking for, but can´t find them anywhere, it seems that no one paid attention to that song before ha ha ha... Anyway, thanks for your answer!